# output error in printing number in c

Tags: c, printing, compiler-errors

```
int funcc(int a[],int b[],int *cnt)
{
    int *c;
    int j,i,s=0;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    if(b[i]==a[j])
    {
    *cnt++;
    break;
    }
    c=(int*)malloc(*cnt*sizeof(int));
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        if(b[i]==a[j])
        {
            c[s++]=b[i];
            break;
        }
        return c;
    }
void main (void)
{
    int *c;
    int *cnt=0;
    int i,arr[n]={3,2,1},brr[n]={3,2,0};
    c=funcc(arr,brr,&cnt);
    for(i=0;i<*cnt;i++)
        printf("%d ",c[i]);
}
```

I need to print the common numbers in 2 arrays..
but the problem is with "cnt" .. if i replace cnt with 3 it works .. 
but when i put cnt it doesnt work

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Have you turned on compiler warnings (`-Wall -pedantic`)? Passing `&cnt` should give a warning as it's incompatible with the `int * cnt` `funcc` is expecting.

Comment: the numbers that showen in the 2 arrays !
in my code ..  3 and 2 are common ... it should print 3 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you declare `cnt` as an `int` pointer, so when you pass in `&cnt`, you're passing in a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. Try changing that second line of main to `int cnt=0;` and change the for loop to `for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)` (notice the removal of the `*` character).

EDIT: the line `*cnt++;` should be changed to either `++*cnt;` or `(*cnt)++`, since the increment operator takes higher precedence than the dereference operator.

Comment: i changed .. it has no errors now .. but it doesnt print anything

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype is:

```
int funcc(int a[],int b[],int *cnt)
```

but you are passing it a pointer to a pointer:

```
int *cnt=0; /* <- pointer */
int i,arr[n]={3,2,1},brr[n]={3,2,0};
c=funcc(arr,brr,&cnt); /* &cnt <- pointer to a pointer */
```

Comment: pointer to a pointer is more clear, double pointer makes me think about the `double` type

Comment: ahh, nice insight, i never thought of that!